# dplyr::mutate_at iterate through columns in function

Tags: r, dplyr

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Date.time = c("2015-01-01 00:00:00", "2015-01-01 00:30:00", "2015-01-01 01:00:00", "2015-01-01 01:30:00", "2015-01-01 02:00:00"),
           RH33HMP = c(99.6,99.6,99.5,99.3,98.63),
           RH33HMP_f = c(9,9,92,93,9),
           RH38HMP = c(99.6,99.6,99.5,99.3,98.63),
           RH38HMP_f = c(9,902,9,9,91))
```

Here is some example data.frame. 
I'd like to set every value to `NA` where the corresponding quality column `(_f)` contains something else than `9`. First, I grep the column number with the actual measurements:

```
col_var <- grep("^Date.|_f$", names(df), invert = T)
```

Then I use `dplyr` and `mutate_at` with an `if_else` function. My problem is, that `mutate_at` iterates through all the columns of `col_val`, but the function itself does not. I tried several examples that I found on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to work.

```
# does not work
df_qc <- df %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = col_var,
            .funs = list(~ ifelse(df[, col_var+1] == 9, ., NA)))

i=1
df_qc <- df %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = col_var,
            .funs = list(~ ifelse(df[, i+1] == 9, ., NA)))
```

I think I am quite close, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` :

```
df[col_var] <- Map(function(x, y) {y[x != 9] <- NA;y},df[col_var + 1],df[col_var])
df

#            Date.time RH33HMP RH33HMP_f RH38HMP RH38HMP_f
#1 2015-01-01 00:00:00   99.60         9    99.6         9
#2 2015-01-01 00:30:00   99.60         9      NA       902
#3 2015-01-01 01:00:00      NA        92    99.5         9
#4 2015-01-01 01:30:00      NA        93    99.3         9
#5 2015-01-01 02:00:00   98.63         9      NA        91
```

Similarly, you can use `map2` in `purrr` if you prefer `tidyverse`.

```
df[col_var] <- purrr::map2(df[col_var + 1],df[col_var], ~{.y[.x != 9] <- NA;.y})
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map2_dfr(.x = df %>%
          select(ends_with("HMP")),
         .y = df %>%
          select(ends_with("_f")),
         ~ replace(.x, .y != 9, NA)) %>%
 bind_cols(df %>%
            select(-ends_with("HMP")))

  RH33HMP RH38HMP Date.time           RH33HMP_f RH38HMP_f
    <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>                   <dbl>     <dbl>
1    99.6    99.6 2015-01-01 00:00:00         9         9
2    99.6    NA   2015-01-01 00:30:00         9       902
3    NA      99.5 2015-01-01 01:00:00        92         9
4    NA      99.3 2015-01-01 01:30:00        93         9
5    98.6    NA   2015-01-01 02:00:00         9        91
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. I accepted the other answer as I'd like to keep the idea that the quality flag is always in the next column after the actual measurements. Your answer requires explicit naming of the measurement columns and since I have several different instruments with different names, it would take a while to list them all.